# Ajax quantity Increment Decrement button plus-minus symbols not showing

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I install Ajax Quantity  Cart Update  Increment Decrement extension on https://marketplace.magento.com/rltsquare-ajax-shopping-cart-update.html
Ajax quantity Increment Decrement extension plus-minus buttons are working, but not showing  -/+ symbols

https://prnt.sc/qq3bvk

Anyone help how to solve this  problem

Comment: Check-in console. Is there any error shows?

Comment: NO, But the plus-minus symbols show default theme, not show third party theme        check   the  video link https://showmore.com/u/tu42o0p